# Bot must add role and remove other, but it doesn't work

Tags: discord.js

I have a command, that must remove other roles, after add one, but it's only remove. I know, that I need to resolve the promise from removing the roles, but I don't know how to do it.

```
case '':
    if(message.member.roles.has('0000000000000')) return msg.delete() && message.member.send(`nope ${b.name}!`);
    message.member.removeRoles([a,c,d]);
    message.member.addRole(b).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return message.channel.send(`nope.`);
    });
    message.channel.send(`bb **${b.name}**!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
    message.member.send(`bb ${b.name}!`);
    msg.delete()
    break;
```

It only remove roles. It must remove roles, after it add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're almost there. I see [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) and [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) methods attached to some of the [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but not where they need to be for your intended result.

---

**`await`**

To keep your code clean and avoid long `then()` callback chains, you can use the keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). It will wait for the proceeding promise to be fulfilled before moving on to further code.

```js
try {
  await message.member.removeRoles([a, c, d]);
  await message.member.addRole(b);
} catch(err) {         // If any of the promises above
  console.error(err);  // are rejected, the code will
}                      // jump to here and log the error.
```

**`then()`**

In some contexts, attaching a `then()` method makes more sense. After the promise is resolved, the the callback within `then()` is executed. However, remember the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of the code.

```js
message.member.removeRoles([a, c, d])
  .then(() => message.member.addRole(b))
  .catch(console.error);
```

---

I'd definitely suggest reading up on [asynchronous programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) in JavaScript.